# Linux Mint won't boot after issues saving .tex file

Tags: linux-mint, boot, init, kernel-panic

I've been having some problems booting into Linux Mint 18.2. It started when I woke the computer from sleep and tried to continue editing a .tex file I was working on. I got some errors which prevented me from saving (I don't recall exactly, but something about "init.d" I think). I tried rebooting to see if that would fix the issue. I don't dual-boot; this laptop started with Windows, but is now only Mint 18.2. I used cryptsetup to encrypt my drive when I set this system up. I don't think I've had any updates since I last rebooted, or done much beyond running Firefox, R, and TeXstudio.

When I rebooted and entered my decrypt password, I got an error:

`[ 0.168867] Error parsing PCC subspaces from PCCT`,

and I was dropped into BusyBox initramfs.

`lmv lvs` gives a warning that `/run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory` and `WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.`

When I `exit` from initramfs, I get

`/init: line 343: can't open /root/dev/console: no such file`, followed by

`[267.751624] Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00000200`

I've tried googling these issues and booting from a Live USB. When I try to decrypt the encrypted volume in the Live session so that I can mount it and at least get my data off, I get an error that it's already mounted or mapped, but I can't seem to access it. `fsck -f -v -y /dev/sda3` hasn't yielded any results, just the fsck version.

Booting into recovery mode hasn't seemed to help either. Just before the decrypt prompt, I get a message that

`Volume group "mint-vg" not found
Cannot process volume group mint-vg`

After I enter the decrypt password, it gives the `/run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory` error again, gets to `2 logical volume(s) in volume group "mint-vg" now active`, then proceeds until

`run-init: opening console: No such file or directory
Target filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init.
run-init: opening console: No such file or directory
run-init: opening console: No such file or directory
run-init: opening console: No such file or directory
run-init: opening console: No such file or directory
run-init: opening console: No such file or directory
No init found. Try passing init= bootarg.`

I can't seem to edit the init file, as some google searched for the last line suggested. I'm not sure what to do from here, and would really appreciate any assistance.